# Convert Json array into java script array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I get the php array from java script using json_encode. how to convert this array into java script array

code.

```
<?php 
  $dataArray = array("Task","Hours Per Day");
  $arr1 = array("Work","Eat","Commute","Watch TV","Sleep");
  $arr2 = array(110,2,2,2,7);
?><html><head></head><body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var jArray =<?php echo json_encode($dataArray); ?>;
    var jArray1 =<?php echo json_encode($arr1); ?>;
    var jArray2 =<?php echo json_encode($arr2); ?>;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this should be closed simply because of the sheer lack of research effort

Comment: So what markup does this actually generate?

Comment: @RobG why is that relevant?

Comment: @Alnitak—presumably the result of `<?php echo json_encode($dataArray); ?>` is (intended to be) a javascript array literal. Whether or not it produces the expected result will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jArray = <?php echo json_encode($dataArray); ?>;
    console.log(jArray);
</script>
```

Check the console output (F12 in most browsers), it's already an array.

That's because `json_encode` produces `json` which is at the same time an array literal in javascript.

Comment: actually, it is Ok after all - the string literal (without the quotes) will be inserted into the JS source at which point it will actually be a well formed array.

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for correcting your wrong statement and removing the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = Object.keys(yourJsonvariable).map(function(k) { return yourJsonvariable[k] });
console.log(arr)
```